# Book with a guy with mismatched eyes who is sent to a boarding school for spies

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read it when I was hospitalized in 7th grade. The protagonist has mismatched eyes and he was told by his mother that he got it during a surgery when he was born.

He thinks he is about to go to a boarding school and when the driver comes to pick him up, the driver drives the taxi super fast and that thing happens where you're going so fast that it feels like you're in a blue tunnel or something.
When he reaches his school he realises it's a spy school.
Surprisingly he's super good at being a spy.

in one chapter they were given an assignment by their teachers to hide a disc that had been given to them when he switches the light off and he'd search for the disc after turning them back on. Every one in the class was found (with one girl slowly turning the disc to make it invisible but it falls after a certain point).

The only person who doesn't get caught is the protagonist as he hid his disc on the teacher himself.
The protagonist also realises that he's really good at gambling and reading people during card games

Also idk if this is important but the book mentions a lot of ravens. I cannot remember if the ravens were actually there or just raven statue.
And also I think the statues in the school move?

The protagonist also sneaks out of school or something to spy on his teacher if I remember correctly
Also apparently there are this one species of people(?) that have different colored eyes and it happens to be their rival school or something. That's why the protagonist gets bullied a bit because they don't trust him.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What year would you have read this?  Do you recall the cover?

Answer (score 5):

Could this be *[The Ring of Five](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/6783137)* by Eoin McNamee?

> The Ring of Five, set at a school for spies, is full of surprises as well as fascinating questions about loyalty, destiny, and what it means to be a spy.
>
> Danny Caulfield doesn't know how he ended up at a mysterious academy called Wilsons. A few of the students are pretty scary.Someone tries to murder him. Even the ravens that haunt the school seem to be against him. Yet he also finds friends: Les, an exceptional thief; Dixie, who has an unsettling talent; and Vandra, a physick with special powers.
>
> It turns out that Danny is destined for a terrifying mission. As he embarks on his training, he is shocked and secretly thrilled to discover that he seems to have all the natural gifts of the perfect spy--most importantly, the ability to betray.
>
> [image]

This is the scene with the disc

> There was a test then. Each person in the class was given a silver disc the size of a large coin. Then Exshaw stood up and went to the door. "Now, my little minions," he said, "I am going to turn out the lights and count out one minute, which is the time you will have to conceal that silver disc somewhere in the classroom."
>
> ... [snip]
>
> She was turning it gently with a pencil as Exshaw moved around the classroom, so that the thin edge was always toward him, making it invisible.
>
> ... [snip]
>
> "Put your hand in your left pocket," Danny said. Without removing his eyes from Danny, Exshaw reached into his pocket and removed the disc. He raised one eyebrow a millimeter.
>
> "Of course. The best place to conceal something is on the person of the searcher. But how would our little newcomer know that? Unless of course he has the soul of a spy to begin with. Do you have the soul of a spy, boy?"